# Relative Path issue within Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service, scratch-workspace, error-000229

I keep getting a 000229 Error that my model cannot open the output from the first task and use it as an input for my second task.  I am using relative paths because the model is intended to be published as a geoprocessing service for a webapp.  I have narrowed the issue down to relative paths because the model exicutes perfectly when i use a full path name that points to the same output folder that the relative path poitns to.  I am also stumped because the **first** output is created and stored propertly using a relative path but the next task cannot open it that output.  Any help is apprecaited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue.  A file extension ex: .shp must be applied after %SCRATCHWORKSPACE%\FILENAME.  My first output was created and stored in memory because it didn't have the proper file extension meaning the second task was searching for a file that didn't actually exist yet.  The littlest things sometimes.